# Android WebView LoadData - Turkish Chars

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, webview

How can I show turkish chars (ş, ğ, ü ...) in webview as loadData?

My webview is:  `mWebView.loadData(detailsHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

thanks.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3552

Comment: i found it, 

if you have htmlsource:
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", source, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
else:
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, "", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Comment: You can try this. It worked on my project...
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827628/after-webview-used-custom-fonts

Answer (score 1):

webView.loadData(htmlStr, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);

This line of code saved me to deal with turkish character set. I hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"ş, ğ, ü ","text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```