# Android 4.0 html encoding breaks down in web view

Tags: android, html, encoding, utf-8, base64

I have an application running in android 2.3.6 (news reader app). I use web views with custom html to present article detail. The encoding is utf-8 and I use the load data function to show content.

The problem is that in android 4.0 emulator (and devices) the encoding breaks down. I have tried using base64 encoding, which fixes the problem for android 4.0 but breaks down the encoding in 2.3.6.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

ps: the app is in greek. I do not see any escaped characters, just meaningless symbols

Comment: I have similar problem ..My app woks fine on 2.3 but the webview doesnt displays the images in the Html when used in Android 4

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution for Russian. 
[Android WebView LoadData - Turkish Chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347592/android-webview-loaddata-turkish-char-problem)

if you have htmlsource:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", source, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

or

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, "", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Maybe it'll help you too.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution cannot work for me because I cannot use increase/decrease font functionality. For some reason, which I do not understand, it seems that data cannot be reloaded after it has been loaded with loadDataWithBaseURL.

Comment: Thanks, it works in french too. This should be the accepted answer