# after webview used custom fonts

Tags: android, css, fonts, webview

I'm currently developing an android web browser. There has some pages used other character like Uighur character, and they display unnormally, so I used the following code to resolved this problem.

```
    String htmlStr = getHTML(url, "UTF-8");//get the html content from the url

    String tmp="<link href=\"file:///android_asset/myfont.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />";

    if(htmlStr.contains("</head>")){
        htmlStr = htmlStr.replace("</head>", tmp);//add my css into the page
    }

mCurrentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, htmlStr,"text/html", "utf-8", "");//display the page content
```

This is myfont.css：

```
@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont; src: url("fonts/ALPEKRAN.TTF") }
body {font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; text-align:right;}
```

The ALPEKRAN.TTF font is under the folder of assets/fonts/.

But there have another problem like that page css losed.
Please, give me some suggession.

Answer (score 0):

May you need to specify the full font url, try:

`src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/ALPEKRAN.TTF")`